# karate - how to match partial string of the field in response?

Tags: karate

i have a json response as below where i just want to match the string "harry"

in autoComplete, id in autoCompleteAuthors

Response {"data": {
        "autoComplete": [
            "Harry Hole"
        ],
        "autoCompleteAuthors": [
            {
                "id": "search_authors_harry martinson",
                "title": "Harry Martinson",
                "type": "Authors"
            }
          ]
 }
}

Please suggest how to perform this validations using contains?

i tried like below which is not working
    * def autoComlete = get response.data.autoComplete[*] 
    * match autoComlete contains any 'harry'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `match each` and `#regex` marker in karate,

***Case sensitive matching***

`* match each $response.data.autoComplete == "#regex .*Harry.*"`

***Case in sensitive matching***

`* match each $response.data.autoComplete == "#regex (?i).*harry.*"`

Hope this works for your need.

Edit:
As requested on comments to pass name

```
 * def query = 'harry'
 * match each $response.data.autoComplete == "#regex (?i).*" + query + ".*"
```

Comment: can we use the same for json array partial match

Comment: Yes, you can. here is an example below ----->
And match response.mailItems[0].attachments[\*].headers.contentType contains "#regex .*text/csv.*"